# Canon MG2550 PIXMA "Simple Scan : no scanners available, Ubuntu 14"

Tags: 14.04, drivers, printing, canon, simplescan

It's very simple! Nothing has worked until now1.... And Canon's website (Europe) doesn't seem to have the right Debian drivers for x64...

[Canon MG2550 Linux Drivers](http://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg2550.aspx?type=drivers&language=&os=Linux%20(64-bit))

I just want a DEB file so I can click it and Ubuntu will take it from there doing the installation itself...

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks.
F

Answer (score 1):

Be happy Canon provides the software at all!  Even though the scanner and printer drivers are not .debs, they are easy enough to install.

Download the cnij* and scangear* zip files appropriate for your printer from the link you provided.  Unzip them in the Downloads folder.  Then open a terminal and navigate into the folder that was created when you unzipped one of them.  Type `sudo ./install.sh` and provide your password when asked. Then navigate to the other folder and repeat. You're done!